# Can i create a mac application using xcode that runs scripts?

Tags: xcode, macos

I am very new to making applications, and using Xcode, so I don't know much about it... I'm using Xcode 5.0.2 to attempt to create a basic osx application which will allow the user to search through a list of built in scripts, select the ones they would like to run, and push a button to run the scripts. I have several scripts already, all of which have the extension .scpt. i wrote the scripts using applescript editor.

From searching this website, and the rest of the internet, i haven't found a clear, step by step answer of what to do. I know that in order to run the shell script, there must be an interface button linked to an action in the implementation file, which is what will execute the script.

What is the action i have to put in the implementation file?
How do i link the button to the action?
where do i put my .scpt files?

I have absolutely no code written in Xcode, it is nothing but a blank new project.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience with Cocoa apps, if you have experience with Visual Studio this is nothing like it, I started by looking some videos from the link below, they're really helpful, he also provide a full course for Objective-C.

http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLE83F832121568D36

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There is a huge amount of aspects to the problem you are trying to solve. Honestly, connecting the NSButton to an Action is just taking the first (small) step! Just a few of the aspects you may encounter:

1. How are the files executed? (your main question)
2. How is the selection interface set up?
3. How to read from the files? How to process the data you read?
4. What kind of actions will your scripts perform? What is in fact allowed from within a Cocoa app? (I have no idea myself to be honest)

Each one of these suggests potential SO questions in itself.

I would suggest that you familiarise yourself with the environment and the language a bit before taking big leaps. Take some time (a few days at least) and follow some tutorials, program some simple apps. The link provided in the other answer is in fact a good one, AppleProgramming tutorials are easy to follow. You may also find [Apple's Objective-C intro](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Introduction/Introduction.html) useful.